# Optional capturing group

Tags: regex, qt

I have a quite complicated RegEx in which I have some capturing groups

but this groups are in a bigger group, and this bigger group is optional

here a look of the situation (I use Qt for that, and QRegularExpression, but I assume it doesn't really matter) :

```
QRegularExpression regex("(.*)(?:([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}))?(.*)");
```

Now I want to replace the match

```
QString str = ".....some text....";
str.replace(regex, "\\1__\\3__\\5");
```

There is a problem now, because since the 3 capturing groups are optional, sometime `\\3` doesn't exist.

What I want is to get empty string if one of the capturing group doesn't exist :

if `\\3` exist, I want :

```
"\\1__\\3__\\5"
```

but if it doesn't, I want :

```
"\\1____\\5"
```

here is what I get if it doesn't exist:

```
"...text...__\3__...text..."
```

I could obviously do it in two or more regexp/replace, and testing existence in between

But is it possible to do it in only one replace ? And how ? And what is the best way of doing it ?

EDIT

As amartel show me, there is no problem at all, in fact my mistake was that I tried to access the 8th capturing, but there was only 7, so \\8 return me \8

Comment: The regex in your example is bad, because it matches empty string. I hope in real app it is different? Also, you are using non-capturing syntax - may it be the problem?

Comment: this is just an example, my real regex is really complicated, I doesn't see the point of writing it here. If you look closer, you'll see that the non-capturing is only on one group, not the ones I wanna capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this:

```
QRegExp rexp("(A)(?:([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}))?(Z)");

QString s1("qA11 22 33Zq");
QString s2("wAZw");

s1.replace(rexp, "\\1__\\3__\\5");
s2.replace(rexp, "\\1__\\3__\\5");

qDebug() << s1;
qDebug() << s2;
```

And the output was:

```
"qA__22__Zq"
"wA____Zw"
```

May your problem is somewhere else?

Comment: This is possible, I will search why and I let you know

Comment: You are right, I feel really ashamed... I must have count a non-capturing as a capturing. So my last capturing didn't exist.
thank you for you time.
Since the question is clearly a mistake, should I delete it ?